# Will businesses be open on Christmas in Mexicali?

Tags: mexico, shopping, event-based-effects

I am planning to spend most of my Christmas break in Mexicali. I will be arriving late on 12/23 and staying through the New Year. How many things can I expect to be closed during Christmas? My main concern is food/restaurants. The hotel where I stay only serves breakfast. So I will be on my own for the rest of the meals? Can I expect restaurants to be open? Should I stock up on food as soon as I get there on 12/23? Will taxis be running at all? Any insight into what should be open in Mexicali (or other parts of Mexico for comparison) is welcome.

Comment: Can't speak to Mexicali, but from what I recall once spending the 24th in Puebla and going to DF on the 25th (in 2006), the biggest dead spot would probably be the night of the 24th (family together time). Though IIRC we did go to Puebla's mall, Angelópolis, on the 24th which was still open till 6pm or something for last-minute shopping. Spent the night of the 24th with a family, and on the afternoon of the 25th, they dropped me at the bus station, which I recall being plenty busy. Then went to DF, which I recall being plenty busy as well. I dined that night at a packed Sanborns. Good luck!

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg so you had Christmas dinner at Sanborns? If so that's a very good sign for me. I love Sanborns so if they're potentially open during that period then that would be perfect.

Comment: Yeah, and they had some Christmas dinner special, IIRC, though it was the 25th, at the big Azulejos location, so your mileage may vary, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time you'd expect most stores to be closed is on december 24th at night. Other days you probably find local small restaurants to be closed, but those restaurant franchises at big malls or plazas are more likely to be open.

I live in Monterrey, but I believe other mexican border cities are pretty much like this.